# Undefined 'VARIABLE' error while defining a function in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to Run but I've been getting **UNDEFINED error while executing the same in OCTAVE**.

I have attached my code below:

```
function [yIndex, xIndex] = template_match_2D(template, scene);
  c =normxcorr2(template, scene);
  [yRaw xRaw] = find(c == max(c(:)));
  yIndex = yRaw - size(template, 1) + 1;
  xIndex = xRaw - size(template, 2) + 1;
endfunction

pkg load image;

#Test
car = imread('car.png');
imshow(car);
tyre = car(200:250, 300:350);
imshow(tyre);

[y x] = template_match_2D(tyre, car);
disp([y x]);
```

The above Code returns the following **error** in **OCTAVE**:

```
template_match_2D
error: 'template' undefined near line 2 column 17
error: called from
template_match_2D at line 2 column 5
```

How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: Am I making some error in the function declaration?

Comment: I am able to run your code exactly as you've posted it and I get `200 300` displayed. There is nothing wrong with the function declaration. Do you have that function in a separate file? If it is in the same file, and that function is the first line, that might be the issue. Try moving the function at the mid or at the end of the script and write anything before that function line

Comment: Okay i'll try that out.

Comment: ^^ ... a̶n̶d or* write anything before that function line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was struggling with it since yesterday.

Comment: btw just a tip. If you intend to run your code on both platforms (MATLAB and Octave), move the function at the end of the script (or define it in a separate file for MATLAB versions older than R2016b). Use `%` instead of `#` for comments, use `end` instead of `endfunction`. These changes are compatible in both MATLAB and Octave. Good luck

Comment: Sure, I'll do the same.